# Where is preview pane for xml layouts in Intellij IDEA 2017.2.3?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Recently, I have updated Intellij IDEA to version 2017.2.3, developing Android Apps, the problem is while opening xml layouts there is no design or preview button any where. My simple question is, where it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it easilyjust look at the picture i have attached

[image: this is when you can check the preview of the layout]

Comment: Yes in previous versions I had them, but after update they are gone! no preview pane there.

Comment: invalidate caches and restart

Comment: I did, no result as well.

Comment: can you comment a picture as well. Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177642) with the legacy Android projects (that are not based on Gradle).

The fix is already available in [IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.4 RC](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2017.2+EAP).

Comment: I would assume OP is using a Gradle based project

Comment: @cricket_007 how do you know that?

Comment: Well, all new Android projects within the past several years have almost forced that pattern. Even if it migrated from Eclipse

Comment: @cricket_007 that is true, but people still have legacy projects, hence this problem is not so widespread. Maybe we should wait for the OP's comment instead of guessing?

Comment: My current Intellij version is:IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.4
Build #IU-172.4155.36, built on September 11, 2017 After update the problem become worse, I cannot open xml files.

Comment: I removed Idea 2017 and installed 2016.

Comment: @Patzu check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors.